# How to get average time in sql for hours, minutes, and second?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to calculate average time and i get for example "2 days 12:14:26.235294", i want all to be HH:MM:SS, i don't want number of days to apear i want only hours, minutes, and seconds ie "60:14:26"
and datatype is timestamp.

Comment: mysql or postgresql? you tagged both. and what was your approach?

Comment: Can you please specify how your table looks and what average time you want to calculate? Is it the average time between Timestamps in your table or is it the average of all Timestamps in a column?

Comment: Average time of some specific users in one column

Comment: and I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT to_char(current_timestamp, 'HH12:MI:SS')
```